# how to get items that hasnot got a certain class in jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
<ul id ='caseStudies'>
<li class="humor crime fantasy hidden"> A </li>
<li class="crime"> B </li>
<li class="humor crime hidden"> C </li>
<li class="humor crime"> D </li>
<li class="humor crime fantasy action hidden"> E </li>
<li class="fantasy action"> F </li>
<li class="humor fantasy"> G </li>
<li class="crime action hidden"> H </li>
</ul>



$('ul#caseStudies li.hidden').each(function() {

}//this will get all the LI in the UL that has got class 'hidden'
```

But how do i get all the LI in the UL that hasn got a class 'hidden'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try the [`:not()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

```
$('ul#caseStudies li:not(.hidden)').each(function() { 

}
```

Comment: @Andy is there any way of getting the count of those items?i want to use that in the each()

Comment: @manraj82: set `var visibleCS = $('ul#caseStudies li:not(.hidden)');` then use `visibleCS.length` to get the total number of items found by the query.

Answer (score 3):

Use **[:not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)** selector

```
$('#caseStudies li:not(".hidden")')
```

***Edit***

To get the count also

```
var notHiddenElems = $('#caseStudies li:not(".hidden")');.
var notHiddenElemsLength = notHiddenElems.length;

notHiddenElems.each(function(){
    // you can use notHiddenElemsLength here
});
```

See **[length](http://api.jquery.com/length/)**

Comment: @rahul sorry m8 i had to give point 4 the correct answer to Andy here since he answered the question earlier....:)

Comment: No probs. Since Andy was the first to answer you have to mark his one as the accepted answer.